# Device Driver in linux

Tags: linux

Hi friends i wants to learn about **device driver in linux** from basics so could you please suggest any book in which it is explained from basics.

Comment: [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) .Hope this link may help you.

Answer (score 2):

http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ That is the definitive book on device driver programming for Linux.  That said, it doesn't cover some specialty areas, like writing ALSA drivers.  For that, find that ALSA tutorial: http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/writing-an-alsa-driver/

Answer (score 0):

Essential Linux Device Drivers - Sreekrishnan Venkateswaran

Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini and Greg Kroah-Hartman

Note that Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition is a bit out dated; the example programs in this book doesn't work without modifications. However, it explains the basics very well. Essential Linux Device Drivers is a latest book and explains all the concepts in simple terms. Better to start with the first few chapters (which deals with generic concepts) in Essential Linux Device Drivers and then go with Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition.